# Java Wait for a HTML element and record the mouse click through WebDriverEventListener

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdrivereventlistener

I am developing a java application to help the construction of selenium tests and I would like to know if it is possible to force the application to wait for a click and after that click identify which element of html was clicked

greetings

Comment: This is better accomplished with JavaScript, not Java, because it runs in the browser and already has an event model built in.  Attach an onclick handler to HTML elements that POST data to a Java listener on the server side.

Comment: The second part can be done with a combination of EventFiringWebDriver and WebDriverEventListener. 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html  and    https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html.  Can you share more details about 'force the application to wait for a click'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions :

*If it is possible to force the application to wait for a click* : Technically the invokation of `click()` is governed by the enduser who is also the owner of the script/program. Again functionally your script/program need not wait for `click()` but need to wait for the intended *WebElement* to be *interactable* (i.e. *clickable*). Similar to this usecase while you automate your testcases you may have to synchronize the fast moving *WebDriver* instance with the lagging *Web Client*. To achieve that *Selenium* provides you the [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) *Class* which can be used in conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) *Class*.

### ExpectedConditions

[ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) *Class* enables us to comply with numerous conditions. A couple of most widely used *ExpectedConditions* are as follows :

- [presenceOfElementLocated(By locator)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [elementToBeClickable(By locator)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By locator)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-org.openqa.selenium.By-)
- [numberOfwindowsToBe(int expectedNumberOfWindows)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfwindowsToBe-int-)

---

*After that click identify which element of html was clicked* : To acieve this you have to take help of [EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) which will register an instance of *EventHandler* which will implement [WebDriverEventListener](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html)

### EventFiringWebDriver

[EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) is a wrapper around an arbitrary *WebDriver* instance which supports registering of a WebDriverEventListener majorly for logging purposes.

- An example of *EventFiringWebDriver* program :

  ```
  EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
  EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
  eventDriver.register(handler);
  eventDriver.get("https://google.com");
  System.out.println(eventDriver.getTitle());
  ```

### EventHandler

- An example of *EventHandler* class :

  ```
   public class EventHandler implements WebDriverEventListener
   {
      @Override
      public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
          System.out.println("Inside the afterNavigateTo to " + arg0);
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
          System.out.println("Just before beforeNavigateTo " + arg0);
      }
   }
  ```

Console Output :

```
Just before beforeNavigateTo https://google.com
Inside the afterNavigateTo to https://google.com
Google
```