# Observe all actions executed via a Selenium driver instance

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wonder if there is a way to observe all actions—in terms of "real" user actions such as clicks—that are being executed via a Selenium driver instance. Initially, I thought about creating a wrapper for `WebDriver` which returns wrappers for `WebElement`s, where I can observe methods like `click()` or `sendKeys(CharSequence...)`. Something like:

```
class WrappingDriver implements WebDriver {

    private final WebDriver wrapped;
    private final List<Consumer<Action>> consumers;

    public WrappingDriver( final WebDriver wrapped, final List<Consumer<Action>> consumers ) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.consumers = consumers;
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement( final By by ) {
        return new WrappingElement( wrapped.findElement( by ), consumers );
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements( final By by ) {
        return wrapped.findElements( by ).stream() //
                .map( element -> new WrappingElement( element, consumers ) ) //
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
    }

    // ...

}
```

And:

```
class WrappingElement implements WebElement {

    private final WebElement wrapped;
    private final List<Consumer<Action>> consumers;

    public WrappingElement( final WebElement wrapped, final List<Consumer<Action>> consumers ) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.consumers = consumers;
    }

    @Override
    public void click() {
        consumers.forEach( consumer -> ... );
        wrapped.click();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendKeys( final CharSequence... keysToSend ) {
        consumers.forEach( consumer -> ... );
        wrapped.sendKeys( keysToSend );
    }

    // ...

}
```

However, this doesn't work for, e.g., the new interactions APIs. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** `EventFiringWebDriver`, respectively, `WebDriverEventListener` seems to be a good choice. But, if I understood correctly, there is currently no way to observe, e.g., `submit()`? (At least [this PR](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/1179) seems to be open since 2015.) I have asked for a way to observe *all* actions, therefore, I think [Java Wait for a HTML element and record the mouse click through WebDriverEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49367957/3429133) doesn't exactly answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Selenium 4, there is an [`EventFiringDecorator`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringDecorator.html), which allows observing all `WebDriver` events:

> This decorator creates a wrapper around an arbitrary `WebDriver` instance that notifies registered listeners about events happening in this WebDriver and derived objects, such as `WebElement`s and `Alert`.

(Note that the class is marked as [`@Beta`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Beta.html).)

Answer (score 1):

[EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html) is what you need.

There is an example of how to use it: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/

The idea is you create EventFiringWebDriver and initiate it by your driver. Then you use instance of EventFiringWebDriver everywhere instead of your driver. And for EventFiringWebDriver you create events that actually do all the magic for you.

**Update:**

There is a list of events you can use: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Looking at the `WebDriverEventListener` API, how do I get notified, e.g., when a submit or send keys action occurs? Via `getKeyboard()`?

Comment: @beatngu13 seems that "afterChangeValueOf" and "beforeChangeValueOf" is what you need in the case of "send keys" action. I edited by answer, please check.

Comment: I see, thanks! Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to observe, e.g., `submit()`. (I have edited the question accordingly.)